# Changing where the X axis crosses the Y axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have log transformed my data and plan to plot this as a bar chart in ggplot2. The data looks as follows:

[image: Log Transformed data]

I would like to work out how to change where the X axis is positioned along the y axis at -4... I can do this in excel, however I would like to do this in ggplot2. The graphs would look as follows:

[image: X axis at -4 intercept]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Where's a reproducible example? Where's your `ggplot` code? [See here for how-to on data sharing and making a good reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061)

Comment: ggplot really doesn't accommodate this type of axis positioning. One solution might be to add a `geom_hline(yintercept = 0)` to your plot instead.

Comment: those two charts aren't equal. you've modified the data in the bottom chart.

Answer (score 1):

You modified the data between charts in your example. While `geom_bar()` or it's new cousin `geom_col()` require `y` to be 0 (rightfully so and you really shouldn't be doing what you're doing anyway), you can do something similar with `geom_segment()`:

```
library(ggplot2) # devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")

# your original data
df <- data.frame(x=1:4, y=c(6, 4, -2, -3))
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y))
gg <- gg + geom_col(width=0.5)
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg

# your modified data
df <- data.frame(x=1:4, y=c(10, 8, 2, 1))
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, xend=x, y=-4, yend=y-4))
gg <- gg + geom_segment(size=10)
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your y-value to center around the new axis you wish to create. Then in scale_y_continuous() you can specify breaks =, and labels= to rename the value of the y-axis (which you transform)

In the example below. I center the y-value around .8 by first mutate() my y-value. Then I plot the geom_col() and modify the scale_y_continuous with label that represent the untransformed y-value.... and voila ;)

```
`df %>% 
  mutate(yvalue = yvalue - .8) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = FACTOR, y = yvalue)
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-.2,.4),
                     breaks = seq(-.2,.4,.1),
                     labels = seq(.6,1.2,.1))`
```

Answer (score 0):

From the person himself, Hadley Wickham: https://groups.google.com/g/ggplot2/c/c3DVxA-zMY0 "this is not possible in ggplot" though the above answers found other ways around this, it is, however possible to change where the axis crosses in base r plot:

```
#global meteoric water line (GMWL) plot 
# draw plot but dont draw axes
plot(rnorm(5, -3, 4), rnorm(5,-40,15), xlim = c(-10,2), ylim = c(-60,10), xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', col = 'red')

    abline(a = 10, b = 8) #add a straignt line

    abline(v = 0) # straight vertical line at 0

    abline(h = 0) # straight horizontal line at zero

    axis(1, pos = 0) # x axis at zero

    axis(2, pos = 0) # y axis at zero
```

[image]